How to glue laminate door threshold onto the tiles below
The image below shows the laminated wood flooring and the door threshold of a room, and the red tiled floor of a bathroom.

Unfortunately, the door threshold has detached, revealing the white floor tiles and dried brown glue:

Unlike all the other wooden floor pieces, the door threshold seems to be glued directly to the white tiles below. How do I glue back the door threshold? What is the thick brown glue that was used to glue the wooden laminated floor to the tiles?

Can quite tell from the picture but it looks as though the threshold has a lip, so there can be a microscopic rocking motion, which would cause it to work loose over time, as weight comes down on its forward edge over and over. Is the brown stuff gummy or hard?  Not to mention the effects of humidity.

It's probably some kind of construction adhesive.  Agree with the potential for miniscule movement probably causing the delamination.  I might consider a more flexible adhesive next time, like maybe polyurethane sealant (e.g. OSI Quad Max).

An evenly spread out adhesive layer, with no ridge to act as a fulcrum, will be important. "comb" it with a serrated (small triangular toothed) thinset trowel.
